Why didn't G-d make us resistant to pain or blows?
Why didn't G-d make us resistant to pain or blows? Keep in mind that prior to the creation of human beings, G-d made angels, who do not suffer from pain or the possibility of losing their physical integrity, since they are spirits. Why, instead of making something of higher quality, did G-d grade creation downwards?

A physical human who cannot feel pain is in a very dangerous situation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_insensitivity_to_pain

This is a great question!
The simplest answer is that pain was a curse that Adam and Chava brought upon themselves and their progeny by the chet. See Bereshit 3.
A practical answer is that they came down into a world of death. In such a world, pain is a blessing in disguise because it helps us stay alive (see Joel K's comment).
However, you hit the nail on the head when you generalized the question:

"Why, instead of making something of higher quality, did G-d grade creation downwards?"

This is part of the purpose of creation: Hashem's ta'avah is to dwell in the lowest world, and this is the lowest world. A world where there is pain and death, as well as joy and life.
For a quick explanation why, consider that unless it is the lowest world, Hashem Himself is not manifest. In higher realms, where He is more revealed, any being is overwhelmed by the lofty qualities of Hashem, such as His Holiness, etc. In this lowest world, Hashem is able to truly dwell, Himself. His Essence can become revealed only here, in a world where beings are not so overwhelmed by Him, and can therefore serve Him with the service of a simple servant.
This is covered extensively in Chassidut. See Maamar Velakachtem Lechem, 5661; Maamarim Yom Tov shel Rosh HaShanah 5666, p. 438; Likkutei Sichot, Vol. 12, p. 73ff.; Vol. 14 p. 123; Vol 15 p. 243ff, Vayeitzei III and the full Maamar Veshavti BeShalom; plus many many other places.
